# Why python isn't entering my nested for-loop

Tags: python

I have a loop to continuously open different files and log data. (test snippet below) Why is it opening all 3 files and only writing data to the last file?

```
for i in range(0, ranks):
    current_data_file = open(current_path + 'LOG-rank-%s-die-%s.txt' %(str(i), str(len(rank0_device))), 'w+')
    print 'Editing %s' %(current_data_file)


    current_data_file.write("Device,")
    for j in range(0, len(rank0_device)):
        current_data_file.write('5,')
    current_data_file.write("\n")
    print 'written to %s' %(current_data_file)


    current_data_file.close()
```

## OUTPUT

```
Editing <open file 'test_log_data/2015-07-02-10-55-11-3-10/LOG-rank-0-die-10.txt', mode 'w+' at 0x7fae50df4780>
Editing <open file 'test_log_data/2015-07-02-10-55-11-3-10/LOG-rank-1-die-10.txt', mode 'w+' at 0x7fae50df48a0>
Editing <open file 'test_log_data/2015-07-02-10-55-11-3-10/LOG-rank-2-die-10.txt', mode 'w+' at 0x7fae50df4780>
written to <open file 'test_log_data/2015-07-02-10-55-11-3-10/LOG-rank-2-die-10.txt', mode 'w+' at 0x7fae50df4780>
closing <open file 'test_log_data/2015-07-02-10-55-11-3-10/LOG-rank-2-die-10.txt', mode 'w+' at 0x7fae50df4780>
```

It should be open->write...open->write..open->write

Comment: I tried running your code and it runs fine on my machine, Can you try opening your `files` using `with` statement to make sure file is closed every time.??

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your indentation is correct , and the script does not look like -

```
for i in range(0, ranks):
    current_data_file = open(current_path + 'LOG-rank-%s-die-%s.txt' %(str(i), str(len(rank0_device))), 'w+')
    print 'Editing %s' %(current_data_file)


current_data_file.write("Device,")
for j in range(0, len(rank0_device)):
    current_data_file.write('5,')
current_data_file.write("\n")
print 'written to %s' %(current_data_file)


current_data_file.close()
```

From your logs, seems like your script looks like above, python uses indentation to decide blocks, so you should intend the parts correctly to show that they are within the for loop.

Example -

```
for i in range(0, ranks):
    current_data_file = open(current_path + 'LOG-rank-%s-die-%s.txt' %(str(i), str(len(rank0_device))), 'w+')
    print 'Editing %s' %(current_data_file)


    current_data_file.write("Device,")
    for j in range(0, len(rank0_device)):
        current_data_file.write('5,')
    current_data_file.write("\n")
    print 'written to %s' %(current_data_file)


    current_data_file.close()
```

Comment: My script is indented fine. Weird, it works on an 8 tab indent, but not a 4. When it should be 4.

Comment: There is no other reason for you to get that, if it is indented , `Editing` and `written to` should be getting printed simultaneously.